# Reading/Writing from/to local files located as part of an Angular project via the typeScript code [in angular component.ts]-is it possible and how?

Tags: angular, file, typescript

I have an Angular application (version 4+).
In my project, I have a folder with a txt file and next to it, I have a folder with an angular component.ts file, as following:

```
FolderWithFile
-----file.txt
ComponentFolder
-----person.component.ts
-----person.component.html
-----person.component.scss
```

From the component.ts file, I want to read / write to the mentioned file.txt.

I'm not sure if it is even possible to write/read from/to a file from a typescript code, which is compiled to js file and runs within the browser.

If I'm wrong, I would be happy to hear about an efficient way to do it.
Maybe some pipe I could use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file using the FileReader API. Below code can be of some help. Try importing the file and if it does not work , you can always make an AJAX request to fetch the desired file.

Hope it helps.

```js
function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    // The file's text will be printed here
    console.log(event.target.result)
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```